# Why wont my PHP Include statements work?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use php on my webpages. The php in the index.php page works, except for the include statements. The echo statements work correctly. I've tried various methods of using the include statements which you can see here. There are 3 different kind of methods. I've also tried using them without parenthesis. The three files i'm referring to in Index.php are all in the same directory that index.php is placed in as well. Nothing works that i've tried and i cannot figure it out.

Index.php:

```
<?php
echo 'test';
session_start();
echo 'test';
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."header.php");
include("connect.php");

$database = 'NJVCtestDB';
$server = '10.3.171.108';
echo getcwd();
?>
<p>Index.php</p>
<?php
echo 'test';
 require("footer.php");?>
```

header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<?php

session_start()
echo 'test';

?>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
```

footer.php:

```
<p>footer.php</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure your paths are correct?

Comment: Do an `echo __DIR__;` from your index.php file and see if the outputted directory contains the `footer.php` and `connect.php` files you refer to. Also don't forget `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` does **not** have a trailing slash.

Comment: Better read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php. Plus what is the point of setting your DB server data **AFTER** you've included the connect script? You should be setting that stuff FIRST.

Comment: Are you sure the file named correctly?  PHP is case sensative.

Comment: Don't know if that's the problem but doctype is not an html tag - you are missing an openning html tag

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a slag in your path I think,

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."header.php");
```

Should be:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/header.php");
```